# Special characters in Function URL

Tags: aws-lambda

I am using a lambda function URL that looks something like this...

https://xxx.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/?test this

This is working as expected (actually awesome!)

But it fails if the user types / or , and it does not submit the text after #

I can replace these three characters with space and the problem is solved. But are there any other characters I need to take care of?

(app developed using kotlin if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to 'percent encode it' or 'url encode it'. If you're generating the URL in javascript you can use the URL object or `encodeURIComponent()`.

As a general rule in programming, whenever you generate a string that has some kind of format, you should always ask: "What is the escaping mechanism". Failing to do so can result in bugs and big security problems.

Comment: This answers the question but would be great and get my upvote if it also included how to do it in Kotlin (as the OP suggests) with reference links :)

Comment: where can I get the list of characters those will be changed?

Comment: @shantanuo you should *not* go through a list of characters, you should use a built-in encoder that every language has. But if you're really curious, there's a good list on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding, and the official  standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986 Note that the lists there doesn't include any non-ascii characters, so you also need to think about every unicode character from other languages.